# Link Spinner to Webviewer

Tags: webview, spinner

I have spinner and webviewer in the same activity. I need the webviewer change when I select item from the spinner. I find the code but i try it and the webviwer not showing anything please help me to find the error in this code.

String:

```
<string-array name="Ragol">
        <item value ="https://www.google.com.eg">link1</item>
        <item value ="https://www.facebook.com">link2</item>
        <item value ="https://www.riwaya.ml">link3</item>
        <item value ="https://cooltext.com/">link4</item>
</string-array>
```

The Activity code:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dropDownWidth="@android:dimen/thumbnail_width"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="61dp">

    </WebView>
```

The Java Code

```
public class WebScreen extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    String starturl = "http://www.google.com.eg", selected;
    Spinner s1;
    WebView webView;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_screen);
        String sp1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
        if (sp1.contentEquals("Ragol")) {
            s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.Ragol, R.layout.my_spinner);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                {
                    selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
                    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(selected);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    webView.loadUrl(starturl);
                }
            });

        }
}
```